# angular mean.io developer prodution uglify error on minification

Tags: angularjs, heroku, gruntjs, minify, mean-stack

Can anyone explain me what's wrong with this code:

```
.controller('ArticleCreateCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', '$filter', 'Articles', function ($scope, $state, $filter, Articles) {
        $scope.article = {};
        $scope.save = function(){
            $scope.article.categories = $filter('strcstoarray')($scope.article.categories);
            Articles.store($scope.article).then(
                function(data) {
                    $scope.article = data;
                    return $state.transitionTo('articles');
                }, 
                function(err) {
                    throw new Error(err);
                }
                );
        };
    }])
```

In the local machine works well when I run it
in heroku (prodution enviroment therefore with all the js minify)
I get :

**Error: assignment to undeclared variable data**

UPDATE  (My service)

```
angular.module('mean.system')
    .factory('Base',['Restangular', function(Restangular) {
        return function(route){
            var elements = Restangular.all(route);
            return {
                one : function (id) {
                    return Restangular.one(route, id).get();
                },
                all : function () {
                    return elements.getList();
                },
                store : function(data) {
                    return elements.post(data);
                },
                copy : function(original) {
                    return Restangular.copy(original);
                },
                getElements : function() {
                    return elements;
                }
            };
        };
    }]);
//Articles service used for articles REST endpoint
angular.module('mean.articles').factory('Articles', ['Base', function(Base) {
    _.mixin({
        'findByCategory': function(collection,category) {
            return _.filter(collection, function(item) {
                return _.contains(item.categories, category);
            });
        }
    });
    function Articles() {
        this.findByCategory = function(collection,category){
            return _.findByCategory(collection,category);
        };
    }
    return angular.extend(Base('articles'), new Articles());
}]);
```

Comment: Does it work on Heroku without minification? How about locally with minification?

Comment: I'll try for it. I've updated the post

Comment: Same problem also in local env in heroku with env dev works fine

Comment: Maybe the problem is in your Articles service, and it's only expressed here because it's where you're throwing an error on failure

Comment: The articles is added there only that error but the service do the work

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. Are you saying that there is no problem with minification of your Articles service? It seems like the problem is not in the code you've shown but elsewhere.

Comment: I mean the article is added in spite of the error, Elsewhere may be but where I've no clue and I've revised all the code and it seems there is no error :(

Comment: I update the post with the service code try to take a look at it thanks in any case :)

Comment: I've the same error, the problem is Restangular + Uglify, i'm searching for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have uglify configured properly in Gruntfile.js, with mangle: false

```
uglify: {
    options: {
        mangle: false
    },
    production: {
        files: '<%= assets.js %>'
    }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, it's because you must use the ngmin task, which prepares some angular libraries to be minified.

At **package.json** add the following line before uglify:

```
"grunt-ngmin": "0.0.3"
```

Then update dependencies:

```
npm install
```

Then at the **Gruntfile.js** added the **ngmin** task:

```
ngmin: {
  production: {
    files: '<%= assets.js %>'
  }
},
```

Remember to add the ngmin task **BEFORE** uglify:

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['clean','cssmin', 'ngmin','uglify', 'concurrent']);
```

The next time you'll run the server in production mode your code will work.

Comment: thanks for the hint but in my case it was the fault of a external script (btw instead of data I'm using response :) ) Run ngmin before uglify should be a best practice